# Web Scraping the screen image from an interactive web map

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cheerio

I need to extract the map component to an static image from:
http://www.bom.gov.au/water/landscape/#/sm/Relative/day/-35.30/145.17/5/Point////2018/12/16/

This page contains a Leaflet-based interactive web map, in which the layer data is updated daily via web mapping services. The extracted image should contain whatever layers that are loaded on the map.

This also needs to be automated so no one will open a web browser and go to the URL. The extracted image will go to a Word document.

I am a Python and nodejs programmer but I am unable to achieve it by BeautifulSoup for Python or Cheerio for nodejs for web scraping as the map is not an img element but a few dynamic DIVs. How to take the map compoment as an image?

Comment: I am still not getting your question well can you explain in simple way if possible?

Comment: Where did you  get stuck?

Comment: OK. Put it a simple way. I need a nodejs or Python script that will take the map component on URL and save it to an image.

Comment: Rather than scraping this, why don't you use the actual netCDF data source provided on the page, and use a raster map renderer so you can have whatever colors, resolution, etc., that you want.  https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/utilities.html

Comment: I think it's possible to take screenshots with selenium webdriver on a headless Firefox instance, you might want to try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window() # maximize window
driver.get("http://www.bom.gov.au/water/landscape/#/sm/Relative/day/-35.30/145.17/5/Point////2018/12/16/")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"mapid\"]"); # this is the map xpath
location = element.location;
size = element.size;
driver.save_screenshot("canvas.png");
x = location['x'];
y = location['y'];
width = location['x']+size['width'];
height = location['y']+size['height'];
im = Image.open('canvas.png')
im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
im.save('canvas_el.png') # your file
```

---

If you need to loop over each layer, use the following code:

```
from time import sleep
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leaflet-control-layers-toggle")[0].click(); # make layer selector visible
layers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leaflet-control-layers-selector"); # select each layer and wait 5seconds
for layer in layers:
    layer.click()
    sleep(5)
    # you can also capture screenshots here
```

---

[image]